# cpp compiler could not generate operator = for class fstreambase, istream and ostream

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I am trying to concatenate the contents of file1 and file2 into file3 using operator overloading in c++, but it is giving me 3 errors as mentioned
below :

*Error : compiler could not generate operator= for class 'fstreambase'*

*Error : compiler could not generate operator= for class 'istream'*

*Error : compiler could not generate operator= for class 'ostream'*

**Here is my code :**

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream.h>

class myfile
{
    fstream file;
    char filename[10],data[50];
    public:
        myfile()
        {
            //cout<<"File3 created\n";
        }

        myfile(char *fn)
        {
            strcpy(filename,fn);
        }

        void accept()
        {
            cout<<"\nEnter data for file "<<filename<<" :\n";
            cin.getline(data,50);
            file.open(filename,ios::out);
            file<<data;
            file.close();
        }

        void display()
        {
            char ch;
            cout<<"Contents of "<<filename<<" :\n";
            file.open(filename,ios::in);
            while(file)
            {
                file.get(ch);
                cout<<ch;
            }
            file.close();
            cout<<endl;
        }

        myfile operator+(myfile &f2)
        {
            myfile f3("file3.txt");
            fstream file1,file2,file3;
            file1.open(this->filename,ios::in);
            file2.open(f2.filename,ios::in);
            file3.open(f3.filename,ios::out);
            char ch;
            while(file1)
            {
                file1.get(ch);
                file3<<ch;
            }
            return f3;
        }
};

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    myfile f1("file1.txt");
    myfile f2("file2.txt");
    myfile f3("file3.txt");
    f1.accept();
    f1.display();

    f2.accept();
    f2.display();

    f3=f1+f2;            //Those 3 errors generates on this line
    f3.display();
    getch();
}
```

**Ps: The code is not yet complete(inside overloading function) and I'm using TurboC3 compiler**

[This is the question btw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn8rl.png)

What am I doing wrong here? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into the question itself. And copy-paste it as *text*. Also please add comments on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: As a hint: Streams can't be copied. So please think about if `file` really should be a member...

Comment: You class contains a fstream, but fstream can not be copied, so you class can not be copied.

Comment: Also:  this is C++ and **not** C.  C and C++ are separate languages.  There is no such programming language as "C/C++".

Comment: *and I'm using TurboC3 compiler* -- Why are you using something from 30 years ago?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ooh okay understood but the question says that I have to include a file pointer in my class.. any idea how to do that?

Comment: @chirag_9121 BTW, your code, if you used modern C++, compiles without error.  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fdb788eb1e521dc).

Comment: A "file pointer" probably means a *pointer to a file stream*, as in `fstream* file`.

Comment: @chirag_9121 -*any idea how to do that* -- Yes, get yourself a modern C++ compiler.

Comment: @AndrewHenle when did I mention that those 2 are the same?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ohh maybe its the problem of the compiler then, thanks buddy

Comment: @chirag_9121 You tagged this C++ question with the C tag.

Comment: @AndrewHenle sorry, my bad, will use more relevant tags from now on. I did that only for the reach. But yea it's wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You are over-engineering the problem. Modern C++, in particular, already makes copying file data around ridiculously easy.

#### To concatenate two files *in memory*:

1. Read the first file to a std::string
2. Read the second file to a std::string
3. Concatenate the strings

   ```
   std::string read_file( const std::filesystem::path & filename )
   {
     std::ostringstream ss;
     std::ifstream f( filename );
     ss << f.rdbuf();
     return ss.str();
   }

   std::string s = read_file(...) + read_file(...);
   ```
4. Steps 2 and 3 could be done at the same time

   ```
   std::ostringstream ss;
   std::ifstream f1(...);
   std::ifstream f2(...);
   ss << f1.rdbuf();
   ss << f2.rdbuf();
   std::string s = ss.str();
   ```
5. Write the string to the new file the usual way:

   ```
   std::ofstream f3(...);
   f3 << s;
   ```

#### To concatenate two files *on disk*:

```
std::ifstream f1(...);
std::ifstream f2(...);
std::ofstream f3(...);
f3 << f1.rdbuf() << f2.rdbuf();
```

#### Compilers

You really should have a modern C++ compiler working with C++17 at the bare *minimum* language standard.

*However*, if there is some reason you are constrained to an ancient, pre-standard C++ compiler, you can still use it. I never learned Borland’s pre-standard version of C++ file streams, so, alas, I cannot help much there. Read the documentation. It may not be possible to use the `<<` operator to simply copy the stream buffer, but that is again just a read and write chars until EOF operation. You can make it into a little helper function taking both file objects by reference.